# JavaScript - check length value

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a form, in this form I have to validate if the value is long enough.... More than 1 character.

My actual code looks like that:

```
function validateForm(){
    alert("Form ok");
    if(document.getElementsByName("firstname").value.length >1){
        alert("if");
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById("nameValidation").innerHTML= "* You must enter a first name";
        alert("else");
    }
```

I am struggling to understand why it doesn't work....

Many thanks.

Comment: [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a list of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) which returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So, you should use it like this:

`document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value.length > 1`

Comment: Ok, works perfectly now! So this [0] refers to what?

Comment: [0] refers to element at 0th index.. accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0]` will return a first DOM element with name="firstname". It makes sense because you can have more than one element with the same `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns array (or array-like object) of elements. You can access each element by index, e.g.:

```
document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value.length
```